# How to move an existing user profile?

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-profiles

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I've been searching around for a while but I've not been able to find a clear, simple and straightforward answer to this question.

I have a Windows 10 PC with an existing user profile, f.e. `C:\Users\Username`. I want to move the profile to a different path, f.e. `D:\Username`. *I want to move the full user profile, not only the user folders (Documents, Pictures.etc.).*

I know this must be done while logged on as another (administrative) user, otherwise the user profile is locked; that's fine.

But how do I actually move an existing user profile do a different location?

Comment: I accidentally deleted the "does this .." comment instead of my last reply.  I went ahead and flagged this as a duplicate of the existing question.

Comment: @Ramhound this is not the same question, that one is about changing the default location for new user profiles, I want to move an *existing*
 user profile.